# Can't get custom sound on toggle button

Tags: audio, toggle

Trying to get my toggle buttons to make custom sounds but I just can't get it, I'm very new to eclipse and I managed to get it on the splash screen but can't get it for the buttons.

```
package org.iimed.www;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class vpbox extends Activity {


   private ImageButton home;




    public void onCreate(Bundle vpbox_activity) {
         super.onCreate(vpbox_activity);
        setContentView(R.layout.vpbox_activity);

        tuetoggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tuetoggle);

    home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);

        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                startActivity(new Intent(vpbox.this, MainActivity.class));




      ToggleButton sb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.suntoggle);
       sb.setText(null);
       sb.setTextOn(null);
      sb.setTextOff(null);
       sb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vpbuttons);


        ToggleButton mt=  (ToggleButton)findViewById (R.id.montoggle);
        mt.setText(null);
        mt.setTextOn(null);
        mt.setTextOff(null);
        mt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vpmonday);


    ToggleButton wt = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.wedtoggle);
    wt.setText(null);
    wt.setTextOff(null);
    wt.setTextOn(null);
    wt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vpwed);



    ToggleButton ft =  (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fritoggle);
    ft.setText(null);
    ft.setTextOn(null);
    ft.setTextOff(null);
    ft.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vpfri);
```

The test button with the sound:

```
    ToggleButton thb =  (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.thutoggle);
    thb.setText(null);
    thb.setTextOn(null);
    thb.setTextOff(null);
    thb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vpthu);
    MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.splashsound);
    mp.start();
```

Comment: What language are we talking about? Java?

Comment: Yeah, java. Eclipse to be exact.

Comment: So i got it working on one button, but i have seven buttons to make that sound and unfortunatley it doesnt seem to be as simple as repeated the same code for each, i'm obviously missing certain parenthesis etc.